# How to turn on only one static analysis warning?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static-analysis

At my work, we have a humongous app that is very old that I would like to use the visual studio static analyzer (C++) with. The problem is, we have hundreds of projects, with lots of code (Like I said, it's humongous), and if I just turn static analysis on for the entire build, we would get a tsunami wave of warnings that would be impossible to sift through. I know I've tried it.
Plus if I lobbied management to turn all of them on, they would turn me down. (Actually done that already... I shall not mention the politics I have to deal with).

Anyways, what I would like to do is to start small and turn on just one static analysis warning (level 6000 type warning). I know that I can suppress these, or enable just like any other warning. In the past I have had success suppressing particular level 6000 warnings. But I just don't know how 
to turn only one, except to turn on static analysis and then suppress all of the warnings I don't want. (Seems like a hack to me).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are considering to use other tools, take a look at this note: "How enables cheap integration of static code analysis into the development process" - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0107/

Comment: PVS-Studio is nice, and I want to buy it. But it seems there is politics getting in the way of that here at work.

Answer (score 1):

[This page might be useful](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/try-analyze-for-free/) to get `/analyze` for free.  Bruce Dawson works for Valve, so the discussion has a game development slant, but is a very good read on debugging and static analysis.

I am in a similar situation to you with a monolithic archaic code base.